# Excel columns handling

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a column that has a dynamic values which changes based on an input. I need to get the values without the zeros and use them.

[image]

Comment: You should clarify the question. What is your formula for getting values?

Answer (score 2):

Use `INDEX` / `AGGREGATE`

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$16,AGGREGATE(15,6,(1/($A$1:$A$16<>0))*ROW($A$1:$A$16),ROW()))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try the next code, please:

```
Sub testNotZeroValues()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, arr As Variant, arrFin As Variant
  Dim i As Long, col As Long, k As Long
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  col = 1 ' column to be searched number (here A:A)
  lastRow = sh.cells(Rows.count, col).End(xlUp).Row
  arr = sh.Range(sh.cells(2, col), sh.cells(lastRow, col)).Value
  ReDim arrFin(1 To 1, 1 To UBound(arr))
  
  For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
    If arr(i, 1) <> 0 Then
        k = k + 1: arrFin(1, k) = arr(i, 1)
    End If
  Next
  ReDim Preserve arrFin(1 To 1, 1 To k)
  sh.cells(2, col + 1).Resize(UBound(arrFin, 2), 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arrFin)
End Sub
```

The code is very fast, even for a big range. It works only in memory and drops the processed data at once.

Comment: @Kareem: Glad I could help! But, we here when somebody answer our question, tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the code works... :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are running Microsoft 365, then use `FILTER` worksheet function

```
=FILTER(A2:A31,A2:A31<>0)
```

[image]